# windows service not executing because of

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services, quartz-scheduler

I was written a service which will execute a particular job for the scheduled Intervals. But After Some time it will getting stopped.

Faulting application name: Xhr.WindowsServiceHost.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x54e5a1d6

```
Faulting module name: commpro.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4c9dd79a

Exception code: 0xc0000409

Fault offset: 0x000025bc

Faulting process id: 0x2ea4

Faulting application start time: 0x01d04c2193b449f4

Faulting application path: C:\SyncTool\WindowsService\Xhr.WindowsServiceHost.exe

Faulting module path:C:\SyncTool\WindowsService\AttendanceDevices\ZkemSdk\dlls\commpro.dll

Report Id: be25365f-b823-11e4-be86-f8bc12a64328

Faulting package full name: 

Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

The above error is showing before service is stopping. and if I restart the service it is executing for some 6 to 7 times and then again getting same error and stopping the service.

Any one please help me to solve this issue. Thank in advance..

I also used auto Recovery but of no use.

Comment: It sounds like you have an unhandled exception in your service code. I would suggest adding some try catch blocks around key areas with some logging so that you can find the issue. Alternatively, you could lift your service code into a console / forms application so that you can debug it more easily.

Comment: @Gary Wright  Hi Gary I have doubt if there is any exceptions in my code the the faulting path may be some where in my code. But it is showing that the Faulting code path as commpro.dll.    Any way I will try to have Exception handling to my code.

Comment: Is compro.dll a library that you are using in your service? If so, add try catch blocks around any calls you make to methods in this library